# Pagination does n't work. if i click on 2nd page its going to my home page

Tags: php, pagination

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}


include ("admin-login/function/db_connect.php");


        /* ===================== Pagination Code Starts ================== */
        $adjacents = 7;


        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT "
    . "tbl_post.post_id, tbl_post.post_title, tbl_post.post_description, tbl_post.post_date, tbl_cate.cat_id, tbl_cate.cat_name, tbl_link.post_id, tbl_link.cat_id "
    . "FROM "
    . "tbl_post, tbl_cate, tbl_link "
    . "WHERE "
    . "tbl_post.post_id = tbl_link.post_id "
    . "and  "
    . "tbl_cate.cat_id = tbl_link.cat_id "
    . "ORDER BY post_date DESC");
        $statement->execute();
        $total_pages = $statement->rowCount();


        $targetpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];   //your file name  (the name of this file)
        $limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
        $page = @$_GET['page'];
        if($page) 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
        else
            $start = 0;


        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT "
    . "tbl_post.post_id, tbl_post.post_title, tbl_post.post_description, tbl_post.post_date, tbl_cate.cat_id, tbl_cate.cat_name, tbl_link.post_id, tbl_link.cat_id "
    . "FROM "
    . "tbl_post, tbl_cate, tbl_link "
    . "WHERE "
    . "tbl_post.post_id = tbl_link.post_id "
    . "and  "
    . "tbl_cate.cat_id = tbl_link.cat_id "
    . "ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
        $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
        $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;   
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
            if ($page > 1) 
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">&#171; previous</a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&#171; previous</span>";    
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next &#187;</a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next &#187;</span>";
            $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
        }
        /* ===================== Pagination Code Ends ================== */ 


foreach($result as $row)
{
     if ($row['cat_id']==45){ //this is category id. restricted for 45 number category
    <div class="loop_page">
         <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>"> <h1><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?> </h1></a>

 }
       }

 echo $pagination;
```

if there is click on 2nd page its going to index.php. please help me someone expert.

Comment: Link to the live site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set a id value in your pagination, and use $_GET or $_POST rather than $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition of your script says that if `$_REQUEST['id']` is not set, it will redirect to your home page. Without reading the rest of the code, you should rule that out; are you passing an id with the page request?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use the tabsorter jquery library 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

See the demo here
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

It is much simpler than coding php

Answer (score 0):

1st of all this whole code is injectable, Please use prepared query.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
```

don't redirect set $id=0/1
You using page for sending request but caching only id. Try following

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
$id = $_REQUEST['page '];
}
```

**You may try https://github.com/saaiful/datatableHelper . It has custom query builder and sorting , searching and pagination.